# Add button in tableview footer

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios7

I have tableview in one viewcontroller. I have one section in that. I want to add button in footer. I have written this code but footer view is not displaying.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    UIView *footerView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
    UIButton *addcharity=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [addcharity setTitle:@"Add to other" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [addcharity addTarget:self action:@selector(addCharity:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    addcharity.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 30);
    [footerView addSubview:addcharity];
    return footerView;

}
```

I have also set height of footer 100 in its delegate method.

screenshots:
Initially i have 3 data. But when I search for particular data and result will be displayed in tableview at that time I have one data so at that time footer location changed. I want to to fix footer at initial place.
[image]

[image]

**Edit:**

As an alternative solution one can add button by adding extra cell at the end.

Comment: The table view does not call this method if it was created in a plain style (UITableViewStylePlain). Check the documentation and make sure the table view grouped.

Comment: also not worked for group style

Comment: it will call in both the styles

Comment: [Apple Docs:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614946-tableview?language=objc) *This method only works correctly when tableView:heightForFooterInSection: is also implemented.*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Per [Apple's Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614946-tableview?language=objc) you **must** also implement the `heightForFooterInSection` method, otherwise your `viewForFooterInSection` wouldn't do anything.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
      return 100.0f;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(tableView == myListTableview)  //Here you can make decision 
    {
       UIView *footerView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
       UIButton *addcharity=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
       [addcharity setTitle:@"Add to other" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [addcharity addTarget:self action:@selector(addCharity:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       [addcharity setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  //Set the color this is may be different for iOS 7
       addcharity.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 130, 30); //Set some large width for your title 
       [footerView addSubview:addcharity];
       return footerView;
    }
}

- (void)addCharity:(id)sender
{
      NSLog(@"add to charity");
}
```

Comment: yes this worked fine...but another problem i am facing is that..I want to fix footer at particular page..It is changing according to data in cell.For information see my screenshot.

Comment: Where is ur screenshot .. ?

Comment: that is search results tableview .. ? in this case u can compare which tableview is showing based on that u can send the footer view

Comment: but my point is that footer goes up when there is only one data in it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42399/discussion-between-shan-and-vivek)

Comment: if i will do that then will footer fix only at one place??

Comment: but when i am search the button will gone what to do. i just paste your code @Shan , its only show at the footertableview not at the search footer tableview... please help me to solve how to add this in search footer tableview. thank you/

Comment: This code assumes there needs to be this button at EVERY section's footer. If there's more than 1 section, each section will get this button.

Comment: @nodebase in that case you can check which section you need button, for those sections only you return button with footer view for rest return as per your requirement

Answer (score 2):

Same code in swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 100.0
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let footerView = UIView(frame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,40))

        let loginButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
        loginButton.setTitle("LOGIN", forState: .Normal)
        loginButton.addTarget(self, action: "loginAction", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        loginButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
        loginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        loginButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 130, 30)

        footerView.addSubview(loginButton)

        return footerView
    }

    func loginAction()
    {
        print("Hello");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure of three things

1- You not implementing this method

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

2- This method

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
```

Is a UITableViewDelegate method and not UITableViewDataSource, Check if delegate of the tableview is set with the controller

3- Be sure you are implementing this method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

**Finally**, If everything is correct and still not working then You can just add the view in "tableFooterView" property of the table to be the footer of the whole table and not only the section